# Why do i get this error:gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, sockets

if i put the ips in the list by hand, the script is working, if i try to read them from a txt file i get the error:gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Here is my code:

```
import telnetlib
from __future__ import with_statement 

file = open('ips.txt', 'r')
HOST = file.readlines()
print HOST


user = "root"
password = "root"

for i in range(len(HOST)):
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST[i])


    tn.read_until("login: ")
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
    tn.write("show slot info\n")
    tn.write("exit\n")
    string = str(tn.read_all())
    print string

    for line in string.splitlines():
        if line.startswith('Temperature:'):
            Temperature = line[34:36]
            print Temperature
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: And, what is in HOST[i]?  Have you tried removing the newlines with .strip()?

Comment: Maybe the HOST you are passing can't be resolved

Comment: so if i use : HOST=["IP1", "IP2"]  the script is working just fine.  If i try to get HOST from txt or csv file , i get those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you need to strip the newlines off the host; readlines() returns the full line, including any newline characters, so you're looking up a host like `example.com\n`.

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST[i].strip())
```

Comment: OK, i did that. Now i get this only error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Did you, or did you do HOST.strip()?  You need to get the string out of the list before you strip it.